# Python Locust how to print to console and debug

Tags: python, locust

I have this Python - Locust script:

```
from locust import HttpUser, between, task


class LoadValues(HttpUser):

def _run_read_ts(self, series_list, resolution, start, end):
    tsIds = ",".join(series_list)
    resp= self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={tsIds}&resolution={resolution}&startUtc= {start}&endUtc={end}',
                          headers={'X-API-KEY': 'sss='})
    print("Response content:", resp.text)

@task
def test_get(self):
    self._run_read_ts([98429], 'PT1H', '2020-05-11T09%3A17%3A47.478Z', '2023-05-11T09%3A17%3A47.478Z')
```

I have tried to print above using  "print("Response content:", resp.text)"

But do not see anything in the power shell.

Where can I see the response?

Answer (score 3):

The [Locust docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/logging.html) explain that Locust uses `logging`, which can prevent `print` statements from reaching stdout. But you can just use `logging` yourself.

```
import logging
logging.info("this log message will go wherever the other locust log messages go")
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, since that doesn't work for me. I've tried logging.debug, logging.critical, print, and everything inbetween and no love.

Comment: oh dang. never mind! I don't know what I was looking at, but it works just fine. Sorry about that!